# SDWebimage incompatible block

Tags: ios, xcode, sdwebimage

I have my code, i download image from URL via SDWebImage framework

```
 [[SDWebImageDownloader sharedDownloader] downloadImageWithURL:self.bigArtworkURL
                                                                          options:0
                                                                         progress:^(NSInteger receivedSize, NSInteger expectedSize) {

                    } completed:^(UIImage *image, NSData *data, NSError *error, BOOL finished) {

                        if (image !=nil) {
                            NSMutableDictionary *songInfo = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];

                            [songInfo setObject:self.listStationCurrent forKey:MPMediaItemPropertyTitle];
                            [songInfo setObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@-%@",self.title,self.artist]  forKey:MPMediaItemPropertyArtist];
                            MPMediaItemArtwork *imageArt = [[MPMediaItemArtwork alloc] initWithImage:image];
                            [songInfo setObject:imageArt forKey:MPMediaItemPropertyArtwork];


                            [[MPNowPlayingInfoCenter defaultCenter] setNowPlayingInfo:songInfo];

                        }else{

                            NSMutableDictionary *songInfo = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];

                            [songInfo setObject:self.listStationCurrent forKey:MPMediaItemPropertyTitle];
                            [songInfo setObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@-%@",self.title,self.artist] forKey:MPMediaItemPropertyAlbumTitle];
                            MPMediaItemArtwork *imageArt = [[MPMediaItemArtwork alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:PLACEHOLDER_EMPTY]];
                            [songInfo setObject:imageArt forKey:MPMediaItemPropertyArtwork];


                            [[MPNowPlayingInfoCenter defaultCenter] setNowPlayingInfo:songInfo];

                        }}];

                }

            } failureHandler:^(NSError *error) {

            }];
```

When i updated new framework SDWebImage i start to receive following error:

```
Incompatible block pointer types sending 'void (^)(NSInteger, NSInteger)' to parameter of type 'SDWebImageDownloaderProgressBlock _Nullable' (aka 'void (^)(NSInteger, NSInteger, NSURL * _Nullable __strong)')
```

After i found solution but i don't know where i must put this line..

```
typedef void(^SDWebImageCompletedWithFinishedBlock)(UIImage *image, NSError *error, SDImageCacheType cacheType, BOOL finished);
```

Please just help where i must put this line and no more.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the new code of SDWebImageView. I have used below code and it's working for me.

```
[[SDWebImageManager sharedManager]downloadImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:ImageUrl] options:SDWebImageRefreshCached progress:^(NSInteger receivedSize, NSInteger expectedSize)
    {

    } completed:^(UIImage *image, NSError *error, SDImageCacheType cacheType, BOOL finished, NSURL *imageURL)
    {



        if (finished==true)
        {
            if (error==nil)
            {
                //Here is the downloaded image
                UIImage *DownloadedImage=image;
            }
            else
            {
                NSLog(@"%@",error.localizedDescription);
            }
        }

    }];
```

Comment: No visible @interface for 'SDWebImageManager' declares the selector 'downloadImageWithURL:options:progress:completed:' i already connected import SDWebImageManager